# SQLite3 not working in Python. [<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f33b6b23030>]

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to get all the rows from a table in SQLite3 but when I try to do that, all I get is this error. I am using Python 3.9.9 on Arch Linux

```
[<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f33b6b23030>]
```

The code I wrote to read the data is below

```
def readData() :
global data
global list1
list1 = []
data = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM people''')
for row in data:
    list1.append(data)
print(list1)
```

I have a doubt that line 5 is causing the problem

```
data = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM people''')
```

Thanks!

Comment: My indentation is completely fine, it looks wrong only in Stack Overflow

Comment: `list1.append(data)` → `list1.append(row)`. And BTW the output is not an error, it's a cursor object in a list.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried what you had told and it works now. Thanks!